# How to loop through the Internal CSS to get the LinkedIn Search Names

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver, automation

My aim is to get the names of the LinkedIn Search using Selenium Java.

Can you people help me how to loop through the internal CSS to get the names of the search results?

My Output should be the names of the first 10 search results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ZVk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arLFR.png)

Comment: Hi Raghuram, and welcome to the site. Could you please formulate your question in a more specific way? For example, include: what language and libraries you're using; what you've attempted so far; what's your specific problem, that you don't know how to overcome. Example: "I'm using Java with jStyleParser and trying to parse this input: [...] but it complains that [...]. I've already tried X and Y. How does one parse [...] with jStyleParser?"

Comment: I am using JAVA to run Selenium web driver  to get the names of the Search Result and Display the names in the console I need the looping logic

Comment: Can you add your implementation code or your research?

Answer (score 0):

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/ol[1]/li[+"i"+]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/article[1]/section[1]/div[1]/dl[1]/dt[1]/a[1]");

}

How can  loop through the xpath in Selenium